# how to check whether the given input field is String or not in java

Tags: java, regex, numbers, character

i have a field called City ,
this should accepts only Characters but not special characters or numbers
can any one help with regix logic

thanks in advance

thanks 
Sunny Mate

Comment: Well, what have you tried? [Javadoc for Pattern](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). Instead of "string characters" (all characters in a string are string characters!) you likely mean something more specific, like "English alphabet characters".

Comment: hi 

input field should accept only characters

thanks
Surnny Mate

Comment: Saying "character" includes things like '3' or '#' or '¶'.  Those are all characters.  Perhaps you mean "letters" or "alphabet characters".

Comment: Hi Borealid you are right
it should accepts only letters

Comment: So your users can't live in a city with a dash, apostrophe, space or dot in its name?  Shame.  People from "St. John's" get particularly screwed.

Comment: ha ha 

please answer my question if know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My hunch is your working on a JSF validation.  I'd be surprised if this expression meets  your final production ready needs, but here it goes:

```
[a-zA-Z]
```

A simple [one page cheat sheet](http://www.addedbytes.com/download/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet-v2/pdf/) you might find  useful

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Character API. Maybe you are looking for:

isLetter(..);

Or if this is used in a GUI then use a JFormattedTextField and you can specify an alphabetic mask.

Answer (score 1):

The naive approach is to just find word letters, which is accomplished by `[A-Za-z]+`

But what about cities that have multiple words (New York City): `([A-Za-z]+\s?)+`

But what about cities that have abbreviations or possessive words (St. Paul, Martha's Vineyard):  `([A-Za-z\.\']+\s?)+`

There are probably cleaner/more efficient ways to carry out the above, as I am not a regex master, but it's important to be mindful of some very likely alternatives to city names.

Comment: Just saw Mark Peters' comment on your question directly coincided with my answer.  I'd have to agree with his thoughts.